# I am having trouble with displaying media in ionic 3 app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am building an application where I want to display a live streaming media for it, but I get the error.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions } from '@ionic- 
 native/streaming-media/ngx';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-tv',
 templateUrl: 'tv.html',
})
 export class TvPage {
 constructor(public streamingMedia: StreamingMedia) { 

 let options: StreamingVideoOptions = {
 successCallback: () => { console.log('Video played') },
 errorCallback: (e) => { console.log('Error streaming') },
 orientation: 'landscape',
 shouldAutoClose: true,
 controls: false
};
this.streamingMedia.playVideo('rtmp://103.130.178.29:1075/ntv/live/live1', 
options);
}
}
```

[image: Here is my error message]

Answer (score -1):

You are on Ionic 3 and you are using native plugin version supported for Ionic 4 (version  >= 5.0.0). Please uninstall the plugin,

```
$ ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-streaming-media
$ npm uninstall @ionic-native/streaming-media
```

And install version **4**.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-streaming-media
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/streaming-media@4
```

And import it without **ngx**

```
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';
```

**Note:**

If you are using Ionic 3, please follow v3 guide instead of the latest guide.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/streaming-media/

Comment: facing the same error even after following this instructions. I am on ionic 4